# Enter the date with the keyboard is only numbers without unnecessary actions

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

For example, `CustomFormat = dd.MM.yyyy`. I want to input `20052011` and see `20.05.2011`. Now to go through the separator need to use the mouse or the arrow button. I would like to enter only numbers, without unnecessary actions.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use a `MaskedTextBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each DateTime picker set `ValueChanged` event to:

```
private void datePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
}
```

This will move cursor for one place to the right without need to press arrow key or click on next date value.

Comment: Honestly, this is a pretty ugly solution.

Comment: Still works tho. I know there are other ways, but OP did not exactly specify his needs.

Comment: Why do you think it's bad? Between to add to the needs of the question?

Comment: I am using this solution in my project and it works fine. If you are using DateTime picker, this is the easiest way to automatically move cursor when entering value. There are few more ways to do this, but they are more complicated and more or less do the same as this.

Comment: It should be something like: `if ((sender as DateTimePicker).Focused) SendKeys.Send("{Right}");`. It's just somewhat inconsistent: the input is moved only when the value actually changes - to the right only - so you need to use the cursors anyway. But I won't call it *bad*, it's just shallow.

Comment: @Jimi Well, when you are entering date as OP said, you only need movement to the right. I agree that this could be improved, but the bare bones are here for OP to implement.

Comment: By default, the DateTimePicker field will be today's date. If you enter a new date and the date is the same as the day or month, you do not go right. Because the value does not change. The event is not raised.

Comment: I choice the way to `MaskedTextBox`. But checked your answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the use of third-party controls, I would recommend DevExpress [DateEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit). It supports automatic navigation between date parts by setting the [DateEdit.Properties.Mask.MaskType](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskProperties.MaskType) property to DateTimeAdvancingCaret.